# Using flash builder 4.5 for php wizard for remote object

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder, remoteobject

I'm fairly new to Flex\AS3
I'm using flash builder 4.5 for php and I'm trying to connect to my DB via remote objects.
I'm following adobes instructions as listed here: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/accessingdata/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-668f02f4120d422cf08-7ffe.html#WSbde04e3d3e6474c4-668f02f4120d422cf08-7ffa

I've created the php service, and successfully finished the wizard. 
I've tested my service with the Test tool and it is indeed returning my results.

My problem is that it seems that flash builder didn't create the service's files(super+base) at all. For example, when I drag the service into a dropdown component I get an error saying that the service component can't be found.

Does anyone know this issue happens? how can the test tool work if the service classes don't exist?

Thanks in advance,
Ravid

Comment: Sorry for the mess. problem is solved. 
I will post an answer once stackoverflow will let me( I need to wait 8 hours for somereason...? ? ?)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't checkout the files before using the wizard so flash builder didn't have write permissions on the files and therefore didn't create the necessary files. 
once he had the write permissions - everything worked just fine